# Using filesDir on AsyncTask (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, service, kotlin, android-asynctask

I'm attempting to run a service that accesses local storage, finds what items have not been uploaded to a server, and uploads them. When attempting to assign my file name, I've been using filesDir in my activities. I believe filesDir requires a context, which the service I'm making doesn't have. Is there an alternative to this? Here's my code:

```
class AuthorizationSaveTask : AsyncTask<Int, Int, String>() {

override fun onPreExecute() {

}

override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Int?): String {

    val startId = params[0]

    //Get data for list view
    var authorizationArrayList = ArrayList<AuthorizationObject>()
    try {
        //Set target file to authorizations.txt
        val targetFile = File(filesDir, "authorizations.txt")
        //Create new file input stream
        val fis = FileInputStream(targetFile)
        //Create new object input stream, using fis
        val ois = ObjectInputStream(fis)
        //write object input stream to object

        //TODO: There has to be a better syntax than this.
        authorizationArrayList = (ois.readObject() as ArrayList<*>).filterIsInstance<AuthorizationObject>() as ArrayList<AuthorizationObject>
        //close object output stream
        ois.close()
        //close file output stream
        fis.close()

    } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return "Service complete $startId"
}

override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    val counter = values[0]
    Log.i("BEAU", "Service Running $counter")
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
    Log.i("BEAU", result)
}
```

Thank you for your time! Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: Gotcha! I won't do that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Service` IS a `Context`. More exactly a subclass of it. So you can call `getFilesDir()` the same way you would in an `Activity`.

However, the code you are posting does not show a `Service` but rather an `AsyncTask`... I don't know where you are creating your `AsyncTask` but you can still pass the Context as a parameter.

EDIT
As it seems that the OP was looking for a way to pass the `Context` to the `AsynkTask`, I edited my answer.

Change your code to:

```
class AuthorizationSaveTask : AsyncTask<Int, Int, String>(val context: Context)
```

And wherever your are creating you Task pass the context.

```
val task = AuthorizationSaveTask(this)
```

You might also want to consider passing just the file.

```
class AuthorizationSaveTask : AsyncTask<Int, Int, String>(val saveDir: File)
```

And in your `Activity`:

```
val task = AuthorizationSaveTask(filesDir)
```

Comment: Of course. Thank you. I'm running the AsyncTask in a service. I'll try and pass it as a parameter, then.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your comment. Also, you should change your question title. It is a little confusing to use the word Service...